# Trouble with Bool in a user defined class as a function c++

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, boolean

Hi I'm taking a c++ course and we are learning how to use user defined classes and I am having trouble with the my bool. Up to this point the farthest I can get to is when I compile I get an error

"No matching Function for call to StudRd::ValidRd()  note: candidates are: bool StudRd::ValidRd(StudRd&) const"

Not only is this my first time using class but also my first time using a bool function. I've been over this and googled for a similar problem for hours, but I feel I'm no closer to understanding it.

```
#include "stud.h"
int main()
{
  ifstream inFile;
  ofstream outFile;
  inFile.open("in.data");
  outFile.open("out.data");
  if(inFile.fail() || outFile.fail())//Checks the in and out files
{
    cout << "input file or output file opening failed" << endl;
}
  StudRd rd;                    //Declares an object of the class
  rd.DefaultRd();              //Default constructor
  outFile << "*~<Student Exam Report>~*" << endl;
  outFile << "Stud id" << setw(10) << "Exam 1" << setw(10) << "Exam 2" << setw(10) <<     "Exam 3" << setw(10) << "Avg" << endl;
rd.ReadRd(inFile, rd);
while(inFile){           //Loop until the file runs out of data
  rd.ValidRd(rd);                //Determines if data read is valid
  if(rd.ValidRd()){           //if statement is executed if bool returns valid
    rd.ValidCountRd(rd);
    rd.findAvg(rd);           //Function that figures out an average for the struct
    rd.MaxOfAllExams(rd);     //finds the highest valid exam
    rd.WriteRd(outFile, rd);  //Function that writes the struct to the outFile
  }
  else{
    rd.InvalidCountRd(rd);
    rd.WriteInvalidRd(outFile, rd);
  }
rd.ReadRd(inFile, rd);                //function that reads from the infile and assigns to a structure
 }
  rd.AvgOfAllExams(rd);                 //finds the average of all valid exams
  rd.WriteFooterRd(outFile, rd);        //Writes the footer containing max, avg, pass, fail, valid, invalid
  outFile << "*** END ***" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the class and function implementations

```
#include "stud.h"

void StudRd :: DefaultRd()
{
  id = -111;
  exam1 = -100;
  exam2 = -100;
  exam3 = -100;
  numValid = 0;
  numInvalid = 0;
  numPass = 0;
  numFail = 0;
}

bool StudRd :: ValidRd(StudRd& rd) const
{
  return(111 <= rd.id <= 999 &&
         0 <= rd.exam1 <= 100 &&
         0 <= rd.exam2 <= 100 &&
         0 <= rd.exam3 <= 100);
}

void StudRd :: ValidCountRd(StudRd& rd)
{
  rd.numValid++;
}

void StudRd :: InvalidCountRd(StudRd& rd)
{

  rd.numInvalid++;
}

void StudRd :: MaxOfAllExams(StudRd& rd)
{
    if(rd.examMax < rd.exam1){
      rd.examMax = rd.exam1;
}
    if(rd.examMax < rd.exam2){
      rd.examMax = rd.exam2;
    }
    if(rd.examMax < rd.exam3){
      rd.examMax = rd.exam3;
    }
}

void StudRd :: AvgOfAllExams(StudRd& rd)
{
  rd.avgOfAllExams = rd.examSum / rd.numValid;
}

void StudRd :: ReadRd(ifstream& inFile, StudRd& rd)
{
  inFile >> rd.id >> rd.exam1 >> rd.exam2 >> rd.exam3;
}

void StudRd :: WriteRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd)
{
  inFile >> rd.id >> rd.exam1 >> rd.exam2 >> rd.exam3;
}

void StudRd :: WriteRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd)
{
  outFile.setf(ios::fixed);
  outFile.setf(ios::showpoint);
  outFile.precision(2);
  outFile << rd.id<< setw(10) << rd.exam1 << setw(10) << rd.exam2 << setw(10) << rd.exam3 << setw(10) << rd.avg << setw(10) << rd.passFail << endl;
}

void StudRd :: WriteInvalidRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd)
{
  outFile.setf(ios::fixed);
  outFile.setf(ios::showpoint);
  outFile.precision(2);
  outFile << rd.id << setw(10) << rd.exam1 << setw(10) << rd.exam2 << setw(10) << rd.exam3 << setw(10) << "Invalid Data" << endl;
}

void StudRd :: WriteFooterRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd)
{
  outFile.setf(ios::fixed);
  outFile.setf(ios::showpoint);
  outFile.precision(2);
  outFile << ">>> Max of All Valid Exams: " << rd.examMax << endl;
  outFile << ">>> Average of All Valid Exams: " << rd.avgOfAllExams << endl;
  outFile << endl;
  outFile << "Number of Valid Data: " << rd.numValid << "   Number of Invalid Data: " << rd.numInvalid << endl;
  outFile << "Number of Students Passed: " << rd.numPass << "   Number of Students Failed: " << rd.numFail << endl;
}

void StudRd :: findAvg(StudRd& rd)
{
  rd.avg = float(rd.exam1 + rd.exam2 + rd.exam3)/float(3);
  rd.examSum = rd.examSum + rd.avg;
  if(rd.avg < 70){
    rd.passFail = "F";
    numFail++;
  }
  else{
    rd.passFail = "P";
    numPass++;
  }
}





#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Creates the structure Studrd
class StudRd
{
  public:
  void DefaultRd();

  bool ValidRd(StudRd& rd) const;

  void ValidCountRd(StudRd& rd);

  void InvalidCountRd(StudRd& rd);

  void MaxOfAllExams(StudRd& rd);

  void AvgOfAllExams(StudRd& rd);

 void ReadRd(ifstream& inFile, StudRd& rd);

 void WriteRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd);

 void WriteInvalidRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd);

 void WriteFooterRd(ofstream& outFile, StudRd rd);

  void findAvg(StudRd& rd);

 private:
  int id;
  int numValid;
  int numInvalid;
  int numPass;
  int numFail;
  float exam1;
  float exam2;
  float exam3;
  float avg;
  float examMax;
  float avgOfAllExams;
  float examSum;
  string passFail;
};
```

I have no idea what is causing this and any help on this so I can get it to at least compile so I can do final tweaks I would be very grateful.

If someone spots the error they could point it out and give an explanation of what went wrong would be incredibly nice.

Also my first time submitting hope I did this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared and defined the function as:

```
bool ValidRd(StudRd& rd) const; 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but you are trying to call it as:

```
if(rd.ValidRd()){      
             ^^^
```

without any parameter, obviously since you did not declare a function taking no parameter the compiler complains. Itcannot find a function by the name `ValidRd()` which takes no input parameter.

Comment: Beat me to it by only a few seconds.

Comment: Now the question becomes, why does the function need a parameter? It should work against the object it was called on. Same with many of the other functions.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, and that opens a can of worms...the entire design would need to be reviewed.

Comment: Adding the parameters has allowed my program to compile but I feel as though the bool isn't working. When I use invalid test data it doesn't come up as invalid in my if statement. 

I've never used a bool like this before I feel like I did something wrong so that it's not returning the right value and not using the if statement correctly.  Can anyone help on this?

Comment: @Tim: Obviously, something is amiss in the logic you code inside `ValidRd()`.On a side note reconsider your design or try to find justifications of defining a class or functions in the way you are.You should be able to see a lot is unanswered in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's look at what the error message says.  Translated, it says "you are trying to call a method named StdRd::ValidRd with no arguments.  The closest method I can find is a StdRd::ValRD() that takes a reference to a StdRd."

Now, it'd be handy to see the whole error message, which includes the line number of the line it sees the error (probably between colons, like ":36:") but in the mean time, look everywhere you call ValRd.